# Couldn't read TokensRegexNER Stanford NLP

Tags: stanford-nlp

Hello everyone and thanks for your help in advance.  I am brand new to trying to use Stanford NLP and am trying to follow the C# example at https://sergey-tihon.github.io/Stanford.NLP.NET/samples/CoreNLP.Pipeline.html.  I am recweiving an error:

An unhandled exception of type 'edu.stanford.nlp.io.RuntimeIOException' occurred in stanford-corenlp-3.9.1.dll

Additional information: Couldn't read TokensRegexNER from edu/stanford/nlp/models/kbp/regexner_caseless.tab

The error is being thrown at the line:

```
var pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
```

I've been searching this error buthaven't found a resolution yet.  Since I've never worked with NLP and have never worked with jar files, I'm wondering if I simply have my folders and paths incorrectly set up but don't inow how to proceed.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't know much about the C# set up, but this error appears to be related to not having the models jar in your CLASSPATH

Comment: I tried following the article  http://programmingloops.com/set-java-path-n-classpath-in-win-10/ but that doesn't seem to solve the problem.  Am I not following what you are telling me?